# MySQL: join performance when using all vs using some PK columns

Tags: mysql, database, performance, join

**We observed that, while joining a table with a multi-column PK to itself:**

1. a join using all PK columns ran in .5s
2. a join using all but one of the PK columns ran in 42-44s

**Other, maybe extraneous information:**

- all PK columns had btree indexes
- the column that we left out in the second case was a `BOOLEAN` (actually `tinyint(1)`) - so the result set was twice as large as in the first case
- this was observed for both `inner join` and `left join`
- no non-PK columns were used in the joins
- running the query repeatedly did not result in a large decrease in execution time (maybe 2s)

**Why was the difference in execution time so large?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a unique index placed on a (set of) PK columns.  View the explain plan to verify, but it is likely that the index is only used when joining on all PK columns.

Comment: Would that show up in the `Extra` column?  If so, neither one says `Using index`.